# How to send entire JSON payload to syslog through fluent bit

Tags: json, lua, fluentd, syslog, fluent-bit

I am trying to send the input memory metrics from fluent-bit to a remote syslog server. The output for memory metrics, when printing to stdout, looks typically like this:
`[0] memory: [1694350030.133389853, {"Mem.total"=>2006712, "Mem.used"=>1872936, "Mem.free"=>133776, "Swap.total"=>2744316, "Swap.used"=>718668, "Swap.free"=>2025648}]`

When using the syslog output plugin, the **syslog_message_key** must be declared for it to successfully send the message. Now, when I set the syslog_message_key to something like `Mem.total`, I successfully start seeing "2006712" on my remote syslog server. However, I would like to send the **entire payload**, as in everything inside the {} to the remote syslog server.

Currently, I tried the Nest filter plugin to nest everything under a single `Memstats` key. When I do this, the stdout looks as expected:

`[0] mem.local: [1694367396.133191260, {"Memstats"=>{"Mem.total"=>2006712, "Mem.used"=>1899256, "Mem.free"=>107456, "Swap.total"=>2744316, "Swap.used"=>737692, "Swap.free"=>2006624}}]`, so it does successfully add the Memstats key.

However, on my remote syslog server, I see blank logs appear. The same is noted when I run fluent bit on this remote system with syslog input (to receive from the sender). At first I thought perhaps there may be an issue with the parsing or receiver configuration, but when using the logger command to send a test nested JSON, I still see it show up on my syslog-ng server.

Observed Outputs:

```
//Using Mem.total as syslog_message_key:
<date> <time> <IP> 1 2023-09-10T19:14:01.132671Z - - - - - 2006712

//Using the Memstats with Nest Filter as syslog_message_key OR using no key (not setting anything):
<date> <time> <IP> 1 2023-09-10T19:14:33.133314Z - - - - - 

//Using logger command to send a simple test nested JSON to the syslog-ng server:
<date> <time> <IP> 1 2023-09-10T14:01:33.708649-04:00 UbuntuVM vboxuser1 - - [timeQuality tzKnown="1" isSynced="0"] {"Memstats": {"test":"hi", "test2: "hello"}}
```

I have also tried using the record_modifier and modify but I get backend failure, and using the following LUA script has resulted in no difference; I don't even see a Memstats key added with it.

```
[FILTER]
    Name Lua
    Match *
    call append_record
    code function append_record(tag, timestamp, record) new_record = record new_record["Memstats"] = record return 1, timestamp, new_record end

[OUTPUT]
    Name stdout
    Match *
```

I would preferably like to resolve this using the Fluent Bit plugins, as they are geared towards achieving this sort of task. If anyone has done this before or knows how I may be able to send the entire record with all memory data rather than just an integer value for a single key, I would appreciate the help! Thank you!

Comment: In the Lua script you are actually inserting `Memstats` field that refers to the object containing the field.  So, the object now has non-tree structure (because of the loop) which may be a reason to fail its load.  What have you tried to achieve by using this Lua script?

Comment: The Lua script was just one of the many variations I tried to create a key-value pair where the value would be the entire JSON payload received from the metrics. Currently, I use the Nest filter instead to nest the received metrics under a new larger one. However, when sending to my syslog server, I just see blank messages, same with if I receive with tcpdump and open with Wireshark

Comment: Also, I have mainly been using a Dummy input that starts off with a nested input or a list of key-value pairs to remove any problems that may be occurring because of the additional workarounds. Essentially, I just would like to be able to transfer a full received list of key-value pairs at the same time to a remote syslog server, and this may include formatting the list into a string message or nested object instead with a Lua filter.